# Specify which implementation of Java interface to use in command line argument

Tags: java, interface, command-line-arguments, classname

Say I have a Java interface `Blender.java` with various implementations `Cuisinart.java`, `Oster.java`, `Blendtec.java`, etc. Now I want to write a program like so:

```
public class Blendifier {
    // ...
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Blender blender = new Cuisinart();
        blender.blend();
    }
}
```

But now if I want to use the `Blendtec` instead of the `Cuisinart`, I have to open up the source, change the code, and recompile.

Instead, I'd like to be able to specify which `Blender` to use on the fly when I run the program, by writing the class name I want as a command line argument.

But how can I go from a String containing the *name* of a class, to constructing an actual *instance* of that class?

Comment: [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). Or you can use a DI framework such as Spring or Guice.

Comment: Reflection is an enormous topic about which I know nothing — I'd love if somebody were to get me closer to how I would use it to solve this particular problem...

Comment: I don't have time right now to write a full answer, but I use the Reflection way of doing this all the time. My 'AuthorizationService' takes a `.properties` config file to map permission names to implementing classes; my 'HtmlRenderer' looks in a configured package to see if there is a class `<Something>Renderer` for any tag found in the input e.g. `<pre>` is found in input, it looks for a class `PreRenderer` in the package given when the 'HtmlRenderer' is instantiated. No modifying code to add a new `case` or `if` when you add a new brand of blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to go through the trouble that is Java reflection, you can write a simple static factory method that takes a String and returns the appropriate object.

```
public static Blender createBlender(String type){
    switch(type){
    case "Cuisinart": return new Cuisinart();
    case "Oster": return new Oster();
    //etc
    }
}
```

Then you just pass in your command line argument into it and you'll have whatever Blender you need.

The only possible design issue is that you would have to type out a line for every class that implements Blender, so you'd have to update the method if you added more types later.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few ways to accomplish that:

e.g. if-else construct

```
Blender blender = null;
if (args[0].equals("Cuisinart")) {
   blender = new Cuisinart();
} else if (...)
```

where args[0] is your first command line argument.